# showing one option into one div after selected two dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, select

I like on STATIC HTML website to put
two dropdown select menus and according on selection, the result(contact details) to be displayed in one div

Here is what was doing but for me it wrong

Here is javascript

```
function setOptions(chosen) {
 var selbox = document.myform.opttwo;

 selbox.options.length = 0;
 if (chosen == " ") {
     selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first', ' ');

 }
 if (chosen == "1") {
     selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
     Option('first choice - option one', 'oneone');
     selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
     Option('first choice - option two', 'onetwo');
 }
 if (chosen == "2") {
     selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
     Option('second choice - option one', 'twoone');
     selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
     Option('second choice - option two', 'twotwo');
 }
 if (chosen == "3") {
     selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
     Option('third choice - option one', 'threeone');
     selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new
     Option('third choice - option two', 'threetwo');
 }
```

}

and here is html

```
<form name="myform">
<div align="center">
    <select name="optone" size="1" onchange="setOptions(document.myform.optone.options [document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="1">First Choice</option>
        <option value="2">Second Choice</option>
        <option value="3">Third Choice</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="opttwo" size="1">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Please select one of thed options above first</option>
        <option value="www.google.com" selected="selected">www.google.com</option>
        <option value="www.facebook.com" selected="selected">facebook.com</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" name="go" value="Value Selected" onclick="window.open(document.myform.opttwo.options[document.myform.opttwo.selectedIndex].value);">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HZNJa/

here is how i like it

http://d.pr/i/BjjR

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did the answer below resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Your call to setOptions from the HTML returns the following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: setOptions is not defined.

Here's the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/HZNJa/6/

Give your select an id, remove the inline call to setOptions, then call the #id.onchange event handler in your JS to reference setOptions there:

```
document.getElementById('changer').onchange = function () {
    setOptions(document.myform.optone.options[document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value);
}
```